# How to connect MassTransit with RabbitMq on CloudAMQP

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit, cloudamqp

I have problem to connect MassTransit with RabbitMq on CloudAMQP. Below is my code

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(otions => {
    var host = otions.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://llama-01.rmq.cloudamqp.com"),
    h => { h.Username("my_username"); h.Password("my_password"); });
    otions.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "recvqueue", ep => {
        ep.Handler<Communicate>(Handle);
    });
});

bus.Start();
```

`h.Password` and `h.Username` are correct. 
While I try to start the bus I get following error:

> RabbitMQ Connect Failed: Broker unreachable:
>   my_username@llama-01.rmq.cloudamqp.com:5672/

I suspect that the problem is in URI address but I can't find out the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I quickly browsed their Getting Started and I can see that your instance gets a vhost that has the same name as your user.

[image]

The image above is what I've got after subscribing to a free plan.

For MassTransit, you either need to add the vhost at the end of your connection string, like `rabbitmq://llama-01.rmq.cloudamqp.com/my_username`, or configure it in the host configuration, along with the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

"Host": "cow-01.rmq2.cloudamqp.com",
"Username": "mw****jh",
"Password": "Oev7ZC4*****cq61ch7u",
"VirtualHost": "/mww***jh",
"Port": 5672
If the JSON structure is to be used on the host, use this format for cloud